# How to store user defined environment variable in ansible variable?

Tags: ansible, environment-variables, environment

Very new to ansible.

I will like to read a user defined environment variable (from the target host) and subsequently use it in the playbook.

I have defined the following variable in .bash_profile on the target machine.

export ORACLE_PATCH_DIR=/u1/patches

Following is an outline of the playbook.

```
- hosts: oradb
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    patch_dir:  $ORACLE_PATCH_DIR ??? <--- Don't know how to handle this
  tasks:
    - name: Printing Oracle Patch Directory location      
  debug: 
    var: {{ patch_dir }}
```

I apologize for being vague.

Thanks in advance.

FR

Answer (score 2):

> Any suggestions as how I can make ansible to read all my env variables?

Yes, source that file and echo the variable

```yaml
tasks:
- shell: |
    . /home/oracob/.bash_profile
    echo $ORACLE_PATCH_DIR
  register: patch_dir_cmd
- set_fact:
    ORACLE_PATCH_DIR: '{{ patch_dir_cmd.stdout }}'
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing environment variables of target host you can use `ansible_env` like below:

```yaml
gather_facts: true
vars:
  patch_dir: "{{ ansible_env.ORACLE_PATCH_DIR }}"
```

> ansible_env: is normally populated by fact gathering (M(gather_facts)) and the value of the variables depends on the user that did the gathering action. If you change remote_user/become_user you might end up using the wrong values for those variables.

Also refer [how to access environment variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-access-shell-environment-variables) more information.